# ms vc++ iostream compile error

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The following code in microsoft visual C++ 2010 express:

```
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


 return(0);

}
```

gives me the errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'
...
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(41): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If comment out “#include ” then it compiles.  I created an project from existing code and edited to the above.

Comment: If it was a stripped down existing project, could there be some precompiled header residue left over from it?  Try a build all.

Comment: _fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation:_  I only see one error.

Comment: Hi Amardeep,

In the <solution explorer> I right clicked on the project and selected “rebuild”.  I get the same compile errors

Comment: Hi James,

The first few errors are:
---------------------------------------
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acosf'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath(19): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
---------------------------------------
  
They repeat for the different math functions.

Comment: there is a PCH involved, most likely. So, start fresh, while creating a project, opt for _empty project_ and then paste the result again.

Comment: The original file was named <myFile.c>.  When I rename it to <myFile.cpp> it compiles.  I'll have to dig into it to see why.

Brian

Comment: @brian MSVC defaults to the C language for files with the .c extension and the C++ language for files with the .cpp extension. <iostream> is a C++ header and will not compile as C code

Answer (score 16):

Change extension from `.c` to `.cpp`

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for my bad English.

I'd the same problem an was resolved with this configuration parameter:

1. Tools bar -> Project -> Properties (or Alt + F7).
2. Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced.
3. Compile As

If you have in "Compile As" field the value "Compile as C Code" then you must change it to Default or "Compile as C++ Code".

I hope I have been helpful

Best regards

Comment: Had exact same problem as OP; I had just altered that configuration. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the express edition installed, but I bet it's because you have commented out the `using namespace std;` snippet.

Though your code sample compiles just fine in VS 2008 prof edition.

Comment: The using directive doesn't have anything to do with the error. He just has an empty `main()` entry point. The source extension is the more likely cause as others have mentioned.